# Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI

Tags: makefile, solr, compiler-errors, runtime-error

```
solr-9.4.0\solr>bin\solr.cmd start

Error: Unable to access jarfile start.jar

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.cli.SolrCLI

ERROR: Solr did not start or was not reachable. Check the logs for errors.
```

I am using java 1.8.0_211
and solr 9.4.0
in windows 10

i first used this command
`tar zxf solr-9.4.0.tgz`
then
go to solr directory
`cd solr-9.4.0\solr`

and used this command
`bin\solr.cmd start`

Comment: Looks like something wrong with your directory structure. Where is your server.jar located?

Answer (score 0):

Use solr version 8.11.0

I used this version and problem is solved

Comment: Don't think that is the solution. It might have worked in your case, but it is a different version altogether.